# Simulation of a chopper type E (four quadrants) in pspice

Tags: circuit-analysis, power-electronics, buck, pspice

Im trying to make a chopper working in the four quadrants based on these idea
[image]

translated to this circuit
[image]
But it cant be simulated, psice gives the next log

```
ERROR -- Convergence problem in transient analysis at Time =  63.61E-06
         Time step =  31.28E-21, minimum allowable step size =  1.000E-18
```

the time of simulation is 10 ms
I dont know if the circuit is well implemented.
It got stuck at 95% and send me the dialog 
[image]
but thats all and dont grasp the idea of the error

Answer (score 1):

Convergence problems are usually a symptom of a current or voltage changing too quickly in your circuit.

A common cause of this is failure to appropriately model the parasitics.

You can relax the simulator accuracies and decrease the time-step in an attempt to help it cope with the rate-of-change. This may work but I wouldn't necessarily advise it as a solution because you will likely be unhappy with the unrealistic results you get back (the reason the simulator was choking in the first place!)

I would implement some appropriate parasitic resistances for your power-supply, inductor and gate drives and see where that gets you.

Your high-side gate drives have an inappropriate ground reference too.

> Do you have a bibliography that can help me, it seems that Im incorrectly feeding the mosfet

I'd recommend reading IXYS white-paper IXAN0010. It is not specific to IXYS parts and will have some helpful information for you on gate-drive techniques.

I'd also recommend looking at the datasheet for any 'half-bridge gate driver'. For example; the TI LM5113. Full-bridge gate drivers are also available, but there are less of them on the market.
Generally once bus voltages start getting above 75V you will need to start looking at isolated gate-drive topologies, below this point there are excellent chipsets available to the designer that take the pain out of half/full bridge gate driving.

Comment: Do you think that lowering the frequency will help to? it is at 20Khz

Comment: Do you have a bibliography that can help me, it seems that Im incorrectly feeding the mosfets.

Comment: @riccs_0x I have updated my answer with some suggested references. I hope this helps.

Comment: Cursorkeys: Thanks Im still working on it.